# How to align properly table column when using `display:block` on its <tr>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

Good day,

Is there a property on css that will align my table even i set its tr to `display:block` , I need this property in order for my print's page-break to work.

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eatd2fyo/)

Comment: I think if you use `display:block` on the `tr` it will brake the table default rendering.

Comment: @Kstro21 no it doesnt break the table properly..